# Assigning a record item that has an option throws compile error

Tags: f#

**I am confused on what I am doing wrong with the Suffix assignment:**

```
{ First=String20 first; Last=String20 last; Suffix=Some(String20 suffix) }
```

**Error:**

> This expression was expected to have type string

**Code:**

```
type String20 = String20 of string

type Name = { First:String20
              Last:String20
              Suffix:String20 option }

let tryCreateName (first:string) (last:string) (suffix:string option) = 

    let isValid = [first; last] |> List.forall (fun x -> x.Length > 2 && x.Length <= 20)

    if isValid then 
        Some{ First=String20 first; Last=String20 last; Suffix=Some(String20 suffix) }
    else None
```

Why is the compiler complaining?

Comment: As an aside you may want to look at [optional parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx) halfway down the page. This will require you to use tuples for the input instead of currying. Then you can get rid of the requirement for Some or None for the suffix.

Comment: Your code has a subtle bug btw. You are not validating the suffix length. :) It might be better to make the String20 constructor private and have a special "smart" constructor that does the validation. That way, you can never accidentally have an invalid String20. That's a whole other topic, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `suffix` parameter of your function is of type `string option`, so when you write:

```
Some(String20 suffix)
```

You are actually trying to wrap `string option` inside `String20`. You probably need something like:

```
suffix |> Option.map String20
```

This wraps the string *inside* the option in the `String20` constructor so you'll get `String20 option` as the result.

This does not verify whether the suffix is valid (has 2 to 20 characters), but that's another problem.

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
if isValid then 
    let first20 = String20(first)
    let last20 = String20(last)
    let suffix20 =
        match suffix with
        | Some(str) -> Some(String20(str))
        | _ -> None
    let (name : Name) = { First= first20; Last= last20; Suffix= suffix20 }
    Some(name)
else None
```

but the way you designed your input requires it to be like:

```
printfn "%A" (tryCreateName "John" "Smith" (Some("II")))
printfn "%A" (tryCreateName "Jill" "Smith" None)
```

This is not as elegant as Tomas's answer, but should give you more detail to chew on.

Comment: This will probably also make it easier to implement the validation logic!